# Resgatar o valor de uma variavel no VBA e colocar em uma celula no Excel

Tags: vba, variáveis

Tenho uma variavel (um nome) declarada no VBA como faço para resgatar  este nome para colocar em uma célula de uma planilha Excel (se possível através de uma fórmula) Obrigado

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOpt, favor ler: [O que é o SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/75104), fazer o [tour] e [ask]. Inserir um [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

O valor de uma variável é destruido após a execução de uma função. Para salvar o valor da mesma é necessário alocar esse valor em algum lugar como por exemplo em uma célula enquanto o código ainda está rodando.

```
Range("A1").Value = variavel
```